# About possible chess variations

Tags: chess-variants

Is there a chess variant for a 6x6 board that has  interesting possible game-play just like regular chess obviously has? Maybe one that has real competitions and is not as long an intense chessgame (that is not speed- chess)

Comment: See this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minichess#6.C3.976_chess

Comment: "Just as interesting" is quite subjective, but I think the link above has some really interesting variants.

Comment: Never heard of Minichess ; looks fascinating!

Comment: Please @Zistoloen, could you post that link as an answer, not only a comment?

Comment: Could one play a type of chess on a 'type' of rubik's cube. Each piece could temporarily attach to a 'square' on one side and then detach if 'moving' the piece. So each move could be moving a piece or 'twisting' the cube. The cube could be oversized for convenience.

Comment: @pablo: it's done.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6x6 chess exist. See this page from Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minichess#6.C3.976_chess.

Comment: I'm a chess beginner, at least here, but I've really enjoyed the 6x6 varients. For me advantages to the smaller game seem to be: Several standard starting positions to choose from, aesthetically I like the ones where black/white are mirrored left/right as well as up/down, ...

Comment: ... quick early game with nobody memorising popular openings to roll out before the game is really underway, lots of interactions with forking and the such, complicated board positions without too much looking around to check everything, more dynamic/chaotic, more about interaction and possible interaction than movement across lots of space, comparatively long mid game, nice game feel, quick end games, shorter games.